# Removing and adding a tag within edit preview

Tags: bug

I am not sure how to search (make sure I am not duplicating) for this on meta even how to "name" the problem I found.

So lets say I make an edit and remove one (maybe more) tags and add one tag. Shouldn't added tag be on right side pane?

(link to preview https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7383822)

Lets see picture it might be self explanatory (I hope)

[image]

Comment: When doing that, also copy the unchanged tags to the right side, such that it is consistent with the diff view.

Comment: This also applies to the post title. It seems side-by-side diff only works for the body of the post.

Comment: Things with tags are even funnier: You can get a tag listed as both removed and added when it's order changes...

Answer (score 1):

**Status By Design** (I'd say)

I don't think this is a bug, as both the title and the tag diffs can be easily displayed with changes on a single line, where as the side by side content would start to look very confused if they were merged in to a similar style.

Comment: It may be not a bug (frankly I didn't know how to tag this Q). I was confused at first that my "added" tag was not "in right place". I was "forced" to reload few times because I didn't see the green tag, now I know where to look for it.